# Did I fry my DUE by powering it from a external source and USB at the same time? If so, why?

Tags: power, arduino-due

I guess I just fried my second DUE in a week. The first I didn't really see what happened, but I couldn't upload any sketches, even if the computer could recognize it, and the SAM would get really hot.

Now, I had it powered by a 12V External supply, through a regulator bringing it down to 9V, and in the exact moment I plugged the USB, with power still on, I got a lot of smoke, smelling of fried electronics :p. Afterwards, I have the same symptoms as I had in the other boards: Green and orange LEDs on, chip very hot, computer recognizing it as a Arduino DUE but not being able to upload any sketches.

What just happened?

Comment: "I got a lot of smoke" -- Yes, it's dead.

Comment: Step 1: check the voltages on VIN, 5V and 3.3V pins.

Comment: Maybe ground loop - the voltage difference between USB ground and power source ground?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You should have burnt an UNO before this DUE. Now, at least wait for the TRE to be release before smoking anything else. It's good to be in synchrony.

Comment: I did check the pins, and I've got 3.3 V on the 5V one, and 2.7V on the 3.3V. Can't remember the other one, but I guess all hope is gone anyway, after the amount of smoke...

Answer (score 1):

If it was the same sketch involved in the destruction of both it may be a good idea to check to make sure the sketch that is involved as well to make sure there are no logical shorts to ground or other pins. [Rugged-Circuits](https://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/) has a list of some common ways the Arduino can get shorted. It is showing the Uno but I am sure all similar rules apply with the exception of total power requirements and other differences between the boards.

Answer (score 0):

As Majenko said you should check these voltages.

Arduino DUE uses the LM2734Y DC/DC converter and according to datasheet it works up to 20V so there is no need to use your 9V regulator.

Also on DUE there is comparator which should turns off a USB power supply when external power supply is used. Look for 2 transistors on board (FDN340P) called T1 and T2. There both are turning on/off power from USB source. Also check them. There can be also problem with all components around USB power. For more info check [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Due-schematic.pdf) schematic.